# Mock observable value in Jest for angular test

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am trying to mock value of the observable for testing. But I am getting an error that 'get' is not available

```
describe('PromotionComponent', () => {
  let component: CustomerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomerComponent>;
  describe('test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      custCtrl.setValue(name);
      jest.spyOn(component, 'cust$','get').mockReturnValue(of(false));
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

   it('should show the customer component', () => {
      const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('cust-type'));
      expect(element).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

ts file

```
export class CustomerComponent  {
  cust$: Observable<boolean>;

  this.cust$ = custCtrlField.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(custCtrlField.value === 'Name'),
      map(prev => custCtrlField.value === 'Name'),
    );
}
```

Based on Cust$, we show and hide html elements and I am testing that if cust$ is false, then only show the html element but it fails

How can I mock the value of the observable?

Comment: I was starting to answer your question when I realize there are some issues. Please refer to https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype . You are attempting to pass a variable as a method name. Additionally, what are you trying to test? Your code fragment does give much info but I would not mock a component variable so I'm uncertain what the goal is here.

Comment: @E.Maggini Based on Cust$, we show and hide html elements and I am testing that if cust$ is false, then only show the html element but it fails

Comment: Try replacing ```jest.spyOn(component, 'cust$','get')``` with ```jest.spyOn(component.cust$,'get')```

Comment: I am also not seeing where you initialise a component reference to the ```component``` variable inside your test file, is it emitted from the example? One more small note - it would be preferable if you replaced ```this.cust$ = custCtrlField.valueChanges...``` with ```cust$: Observable<boolean> = custCtrlField.valueChanges...; ``` as having an undefined variable which later gets assigned during module evaluation is redundant.

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas That is in the test file where let component = CustomerComponent and that is fine. I have the assigned the type as well but it does not work. 

ALso jest.spyOn(component.cust$,'get') does not work